# Save YouTube ad

Tags: youtube, screen-capture, advertisements

I'm doing some research and would like to save some YouTube **ads** to a local video file. No, I'm not interested in the videos themselves but the ads that show before or during the video plays. None of the online rippers saves the ads and doing a screen capture with something like Camtasia records the "Skip Ad" button and other overlays.
I would preferably like to store the raw ad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the Id of the Ad by

- right click on the video and select "Stats for nerds"
- then you will see the Id for that Ad
- you can copy it and paste it in the url for Youtube and it will be opened as a
  normal video

and you can use a free downloader to download it (my recommendatin is [Xtreme Download Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/))

Comment: Without having tested it, I can confirm that I once could get the ID of the ad that I wanted using the right-click menu.

Answer (score 4):

While on the ad video, right click on the video and select *Copy debug info*. Paste in your notepad, then note the value of `addebug_videoId`.

Then you can use the github program called "youtube-dl". Use: [`youtube-dl` command](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/) to download it, e.g.

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REPLACE_WITH_ad_debug_videoId
```

Comment: Using this method, I was able to extract the video but not download it because `youtube-dl` threw an error. But nevertheless, useful info

Comment: The key is now `addebug_videoId`. And it works.

Comment: youtube-dl also has `--include-ads`, although it is marked as experimental

Answer (score 0):

When using Firefox with the Firebug extension, you can open a network monitor.

https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel

Any downloaded video should appear at the media tab. You can query the URL and download it with a tool of your choice. See for example the cURL part in the provided link.

Comment: The thing is that HLS files are downloaded (in my case) in chunks of around 150k so I need to put them together which is a pain (plus there is no audio).

Answer (score 0):

If someone see this and doesn't know where to put the Id of the video, check this example out:

This is the ID of the video:
WhNqZG_AO50

This is a common URL from Youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izbQZ0gvs-A

So if you have to put the new ID after the "=". You'll get this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhNqZG_AO50

That's it ::)

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like OBS, (OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) is free and open source software for video recording).

This way you could record the YouTube ads to a local video file.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to save some youtube video advertisements the question was how to find the URL of the youtube video advertisement  I was able to find the video and save it for my future work I followed this video
https://youtu.be/vU3TvPTt0Rg